# Search and 'in-place' replace strings in binary file

Tags: sed, command-line, regular-expression, editors, binary

I want search and 'in-place' replace strings in binary file (case-sensitive, colon-separated strings). What method would be more clean, `sed` or `bbe`?

```
sed -i.bak 's/F:O:0/B:A:R/g' file.bin

bbe -e 's/F:O:0/B:A:R/' infile > outfile
```

Additionally, I have perl 5 installed (v5.22.1)

Comment: I think sed can't edit binary files.

Comment: Is there any difference, when the task is to replace textual chars, not binary digits data?